# '$' is not defined when Replacing JSON with Jquery in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, reactjs

I am learning ReactJS for a web application that uses JQuery to load JSON-encoded data from a remote source.

In this sample, this.state is manually set to JSON-encoded data

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Projects from './Components/Projects';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      projects: [
        {
          title: 'Buisness Website',
          category: 'Web Design'
        },
        {
          title: 'Social App',
          category: 'Mobile Development'
        },
        {
          title: 'Ecommerce Shopping Cart',
          category: 'Web Development'
        }
      ]
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        My App
        <Projects projects={this.state.projects}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I would like to use Jquery to load the data from a remote location. I tried

```
this.state =  $.getJSON('remote.json', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
});
```

Unfortunately, when running the site, I get an error: '$' is not defined. How can I fix this? Please note that I included

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

in the head of index.html

EDIT: Keep in mind that the JSON file will not be local.

Comment: you forgot some jquery versions :)) why do you have 2 jquery files?

Comment: you need to import `$` from `jquery`, like this: `import $ from 'jquery';` check this answer, it will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44259149/5185595

Comment: @madalin_ivascu editied :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding, you want to use jquery on your project. To fix your issue, you just have to install jquery and include it in your project, like so in your command line:

```
npm install --save jquery
```

then on the file that uses jquery, import it:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

It looks like you are trying to set a state based on the result of the `getJSON` method, a correct way of doing it would be something like this:

```js
$.getJSON('remote.json',(data) => {
  this.setState({ myStateData: data })
});
```

An alternative, would be to use the [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), and your code would look something like this:

```js
fetch('remote.json').then(data => this.setState({ myStateData: data }));
```

The above examples assume your state has the property myStateData.

Comment: Works perfectly now.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using Jquery to load a localJSON file you can configure your webpack

First install `json-loader` with

```
npm i json-loader --save-dev
```

Then configure your webpack with this loader

```
loaders: [
  { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json' },
  // other loaders 
]
```

Now in your file you can import your json like

```
   import remote from '.path/to/remote.json';
```

However if your json files are remote, you have multiple options to do ajax requests

You can use packages like `axios`, `node-fetch`, `jquery`

Since you are using jquery , you should install

```
   npm install -S jquery
```

and import as

```
  import $ from 'jquery'
```

Comment: Will this work if the JSON file is not local? I have been keeping it local for testing purposes, but eventually I will want to retrieve it from a server. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: No it wont work, for remote files. In that case its better to have ajax request with npm packages node-fetch or axios.